# Accessing static Application method from RunTime created class in spring fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, applicationcontext

I have two projects A and B. I'm adding B as a pom dependecy of A.
My project A is a `springboot` application that has a `Application.java` class which implements `ApplicationContextAware`
Project B also has a `App.java` class that implements the `ApplicationContextAware`. In both I add the ApplicationContext to a static variable `context`

```
@Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
```

When I start `A`, and try to get a Bean of `A` from `B` using the `context` like :

```
 Class<?> klass = Class.forName(klassName);
 Myclass myclass = (MyClass) App.context.getBean(klass)
```

Application B has a class `1` that has a method `init()` that basically instantiates another class `2` with some external config parameters. The problem happens in the constructor of the class `2` where I try to create the bean for `Myclass`.

I get `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException : No qualifying bean of type Myclass`, However if I check(debugging) for `App.context.classLoader()` I can see my class defined there.

Another weird behaviour is that if I try to see `Application.context` from this debugging breakpoint, the `context` is null. This same `static` context is not null when I access this same attribute from the classes of project A.

I tested to add B to project A as an folder(copying everything) instead of using it as a jar. This made it work! So I think I have some problem with spring contexts here. But I really don't know what else to do.

Any suggestions would help,

Thanks!

Comment: First, do you really need all this to be static?  That's awful brittle and could lead to memory leaks if you ever do things like undeploy.  If you're committed to a static reference to your app context, can you add some more details about what's getting set where?

Comment: I have to have this static reference because there are some legacy code in this app that are not a spring bean, so I can't inject my beans in them. 
I'll try to add some more code to my question

Comment: Sorry, are these separate applications? or is one just a jar?